# Should I turn off Warnings Mode in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, settings, performance, compiler-optimization

**Some Background:**

I make Box2D games using WCK, which is an alchemy port of Box2D with a Flash IDE friendly interface.

WCK is component heavy, and also has a SWC that you must include.

basically as soon as i setup a basic World and a Static and Dynamic body (a falling box and the ground) the compile time has gone from a few seconds (empty project, or even just art) to 20-40 seconds!  as i add more and more body types (and components) it gradually becomes more and more tedious to compile, by the end of the project i feel like it takes a half hour minimum to debug something if i have to compile several times to trace some info about the bug to track it down.

**About The Question**

Today I was despritely looking for ways to prevent this from plaguing future projects.

I looked into trying to take all of WCK references (World, Bodies, etc) and compiling them when ever they change into a SWC.  or RSL.  (this would have been a mess, i really don't want to do this.)

I eventually stumbled on the drastic effect that some publish settings have, and i narrowed it down to Warning Mode.  as soon as i turn this OFF. my compile times pick right back up to acceptable ranges 5-10 seconds.

I did some digging on what this feature does, and i don't think it is useful to me. and im surprised it's left on by default in Flash CS5.

from what i understand, according to Adobe, the purpose of Warnings Mode is to help correct an as2 developer who is transitioning to as3.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fa4a.html
"Warnings Mode reports extra warnings that are useful for discovering incompatibilities when updating ActionScript 2.0 code to ActionScript 3.0."

another post about the topic

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=931

If it really is just to give me AS2 related errors like "onEnterFrame is not supported in as3" would they really leave it on by default in CS5? 3 generations past as2...

**The Question**

I do not make AS2 errors, i have been coding in AS3 only for years.  If i turn Warning Mode off am I going to miss any important debug info?

Comment: Is this "Warning Mode" also something found in "Flash Builder"? And if so, do you know where I can find it to disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly doubt you need to leave it on.  You're steeped sufficiently in AS3 that you're not going to make old AS2 mistakes.  I don't see the value in it for you.

Comment: that is what i want to hear :)  i just wans't sure if that was its only purpose.  thanks.